# Android TV (Leanback Launcher) - The softkeyboard from android developer doesn't work

Tags: android, android-input-method, android-tv

I would like to create my own IME on Android TV, so I tried the SoftKeyboard provided by Android (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/) without results (the keyboard isn't diplayed) except on a touchable device, my phone.

The point is the SoftKeyboard is touchable and work on mobile so, in my case, on Android TV, the keyboard have to work with a remote control like the leanback keyboard of Android.

Is there a way doesn't explain to create an InputMethodService for Android TV ?

Any idea or specific documentation for Android TV ?

FYI, I tried on Android 5.0.2 with the Leanback Launcher and Nexus Player.

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation about How to create android apps for Android TV :
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/index.html

Before developing any app for TV first check this [CheckList](http://developer.android.com/training/tv/publishing/checklist.html).

### Is there a way doesn't explain to create an InputMethodService for Android TV ?

check here : http://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input.html#dpad

Hope it will help.!!

Comment: My trouble isn't about create an Android TV app but is about create an IME like Leanback IME devoloped by Google. And I tried their sample without success (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/).

So thank you for response

Comment: @Matt R. : Yeah I want to consider you that for leanback there is no api provided using which we can develop keyboard. Android keyboard is for touch devices and android TV is totally different scenario. So for that you have to do it by your own.!!

Comment: Yes you're right, I have to create my own IME, and I don't know how.
I hoped the softkeyboard(developed by google)or other tutorial in the internet have the same behavior on AndroidTV as touchable devices,it's for this reason I headed to this solution but it doesn't work.The reason is,as you said,the device I use isn't touchable.
The simple override of InputMethodService doesn't work ,it means maybe the InputMethodService lifecycle or something else are different.
I don't know how the Leanback IME is developed but I have to do the same behavior to launch and display my own IME.

Comment: If you have any idea I take it :)

Thank you again for help me

Comment: @Matt R.: You need this only for your application or whole android system like keyboard .??

Comment: Yes it's for the whole android system. So an InputMethodService implementation.

Comment: @MattR. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @defhlt did you find any solution?